# condition of window width for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to js and trying to apply some lines of code only when the window is larger than 768 pixels.

I've come up with this:

```
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    const central = document.querySelector('.central');

    const tl = new TimelineMax();

    tl.fromTo(central,1,{height:'0vh'},{height:'80vh'})
    .fromTo(central,1,{width:'100vw'},{width:'80vw'});
 }
```

Loading in the HTML file this two lines:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TimelineMax.min.js" 
integrity="sha256-fIkQKQryItPqpaWZbtwG25Jp2p5ujqo/NwJrfqAB+Qk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js" 
integrity="sha256-lPE3wjN2a7ABWHbGz7+MKBJaykyzqCbU96BJWjio86U=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='js.js'></script>
```

Without the *if* condition it runs fine, so the condition is wrongly applied, can you help me to fix it?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the condition though.

Comment: @Cerbrus that's weird, there is no effect in any width

Comment: @santimirandarp depends on when the function gets called

Comment: it's at the end of the document, right before </body> @KrishnaPrashatt

Comment: Meaning that it will be executed only once and the working of the condition entirely depends on the window's size at the time of execution.

Comment: @Cerbrus maybe something missed in the html file? I'll upload the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine it with a resize event

```
$(window).resize(function() {
 if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    const central = document.querySelector('.central');

    const tl = new TimelineMax();

    tl.fromTo(central,1,{height:'0vh'},{height:'80vh'})
    .fromTo(central,1,{width:'100vw'},{width:'80vw'});
 }
}).resize();
```

Added **.resize()** which will call the **window.resize** event on load.

Comment: It works for me. Try debugging the code the issue might be in some other code

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen to the window resize method.
Using vanilla Js you can wrap the main function like so:
`

```
function responsiveFeature(){
  if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    const central = document.querySelector('.central');
    const tl = new TimelineMax();
    tl.fromTo(central,1,{height:'0vh'},{height:'80vh'})
    .fromTo(central,1,{width:'100vw'},{width:'80vw'});
  }
}
`
```

then run the code on page loaded :
`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    responsiveFeature();
});
```

`and trigger the resize event :`

```
window.addEventListener('resize',(event) => {
    responsiveFeature();
});
```

`